# Redirect to module after login Yii

Tags: php, redirect, yii, module

Building a site in yii, where there are 3 types of users.
In the UserIdentity::authenticate() I set the type of user like this. `$this->setState('role', $user->role->id);` Depending on this type, i want to redirect to a module belonging to this type of user. To be more specific; if Yii::app()->user->role == 3 I want to redirect to the default page of the module called 'tradesman'.
This is what I got in SiteController::actionLogin():

```
/**
 * Displays the login page
 */
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;
    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            switch(Yii::app()->user->role){
                case 3:
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->tradesman);
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

The redirect to the module doesn't work this way. I'am getting the Php notice 'Trying to get property of non-object'. I've then made a method 'defaultUrl in the TradesmanModule which returns `Yii::app()->createUrl($this->getId() . '/default/index');`. I tried to redirect to `Yii::app()->controller->module->defaultUrl`, but the result was the same.

I also tried `$this->redirect('tradesman/default/index');` & `$this->redirect('application.modules.tradesman');` but then i'am getting a 404 error saying 'The system is unable to find the requested action "tradesman".'.

If I am logged in as a user with role 3, and I navigate to the default url of the module, it does work. But how can i redirect?

Comment: Show your UrlManager rules configs

Comment: If you helped my answer - no :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$this->redirect('/tradesman/default/index')` and make sure that in module exists `DefaultController` and it's action `actionIndex`

**UPDATED:**
@Николай Конев is right, it's just redirects to the url `/tradesman/default/index`, not route. For redirecting by route:

> ```
> $this->redirect( array('/tradesman/default/index') )
> ```

it's absolute route to module `tradesman`, controller `default` and action `index`. If you want redirects to controller in the same module you may use this code:

> ```
> $this->redirect( array('default/index') )
> ```

And if you want redirects to the main application controllers you need to use:

> ```
> $this->redirect( array('/default/index') ) // with "/" at the beginning
> ```

Thanks to @Николай Конев again

Answer (score 1):

To ensure route is working, you have to pass array to `CController::redirect()`:

```
    // for example
    $this->redirect(['/route/starts/from/slash']);
    // your case
    $this->redirect(['/tradesman/default/index']);
```

In other case you will have redirect broken on url rules change.